# How to select a shared gitlab runner with docker installed on?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Its my first time to set a CI/CD using gitlab.com and I would like to use Gitlab's shared runners for my project.
My CI/CD process uses a docker-compose file which I build and deploy.

I saw that there is an option to select a gitlab-runner instance that has docker installed on so I will be able to run my CI/CD process on it.
With that being said, I can't find a way to configure a specific shared gitlab-runner to my project.

Will be happy to get your help here, how can I assign a specific shared gitlab-runner to my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) to select runners, but in your case this is not necessary. You can just specify that the image is **docker** and attach a service container of **docker:dind** and your project will build on shared runners.

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind
```